# Replacing DC connection of 0 AWG with two 4 AWG cable

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

My Inverter is connected to my 300ah 12v battery bank via 0 AWG cables, I want to insert a circuit breaker into the positive connecting cable, I don't want to cut the cable but can I add a section of double AWG 4 cables to insert the circuit breaker into the positive connection?

Comment: Where are you on this planet? What make and model is this breaker you are trying to add to your system?

Comment: What is the distance? Where is the circuit breaker located relative to the battery and/or inverter?  Is there a good reason the inverter can't be near the battery and carry the power on 120/240V cable instead of 12V?  Also copper or aluminum?

Comment: If you only have 300 AH of battery bank I don’t see you needing that large wires. 2ea #4 wires are good for 140 amps where 1/0 is 125 on the 60 degree table. But depending on you wire routing their would need to be derating for more than 3 current Cary conductors.

Comment: @EdBeal -- note that on low-voltage, large-capacity DC systems, voltage drop (vs. ampacity) is the controlling parameter for wire sizing

Comment: I absolutely understand voltage drop, 300ah is a tiny tiny battery bank at 12v I have never put in a “bank” that small it is tiny, so my statement stands that small of a system.